# Laravel 8 application - Unable to reach the site when i try to download zipped file

Tags: php, laravel, zip, response

I am new to the forum, I hope I have complied with all the forum guidelines in posting my answer.

In my web application that I am developing with Laravel 8, I need to download .zip files
To do this, looking online I decided to use the `maennchen/zipstream-php` package.

For the creation of the zip I followed the guidelines of the package documentation and then download the newly created .zip.

But as in the title, when from my view I click on the `download file` button I get the error message `Unable to reach the site`.

This is my code but I can't figure out what this error is coming from.

```
public function exportZipFile(Request $request){

            // create a new zipstream object
            $zip = new \ZipStream\ZipStream('example.zip', $options);

            // create a file named 'hello.txt'
            $zip->addFile('hello.txt', 'This is the contents of hello.txt');

            // add a file named 'some_image.jpg' from a local file 'path/to/image.jpg'
            $zip->addFileFromPath('some_image.jpg', 'path/to/image.jpg');

            // add a file named 'goodbye.txt' from an open stream resource
            $fp = tmpfile();
            fwrite($fp, 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');
            rewind($fp);
            $zip->addFileFromStream('goodbye.txt', $fp);
            fclose($fp);

            $response = Response::create(200);
            $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
            $response->header('Cache-Control', 'public');
            $response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="file.zip"');
            
            return $response()->stream(function() use ($zip){
                $zip->finish();
            });

}
```

I appreciate any advice or suggestions
Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: Are you sure about $response->steam? Shouldn't it be $response->streamDownload? And it looks like zip->finish already set headers and makes it's own response. I doubt that you need zip->finish. Your $fp is actually a file, why don't simple use it like: response()->download($pathToFile);

Comment: @CyberAleks, hi I used `$response->stream()` because I followed a procedure found online.
As well as the use of `$zip->finish()` I always got it from that guide.
To answer your last question, I don't save the .zip file so I don't know which path to go to, as i create and download it.